# Does anyone know when the three commands under Magento2 will be available

Tags: command-line

Does anyone know when the three commands under Magento2 will be available?

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content
```

Comment: available means ? they already available..

Comment: if they're unavailable it could be that your Magento instance isn't installed. Check your database and make sure composer packages are installed. To install Magento use the `bin/magento setup:install` command.

Answer (score 0):

**This command must be executed at the root of the site**.
Check the existence of the file.

```
ls -l bin/magento
```

You sould have something like this

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 username username 799 Dec  1 09:55 bin/magento*
```

---

- **If you see that**

*-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 799 Dec  1 09:55 bin/magento*

bin/magento is not executable then make the file executable

```
chmod +x bin/magento
```

or

```
sudo chmod +x bin/magento
```

And retry your command

---

- **If the response is like this**

*/bin/ls: cannot access bin/magento: No such file or directory*

**Check all your install**